# Bootstrap w. Kendo UI - Responsive Tables

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap with Kendo UI. I'm looking to create a responsive table.

Bootstraps documentation says to just wrap **.table** with a **.table-responsive** class.

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive
>   to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When
>   viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any
>   difference in these tables.

[Source:  Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when using Kendo UI's grid.

In the following example, I apply the **.table** class to my Kendo grid, and wrap it with the **.table-responsive** class as per documentation.

Long story short, my table is not responsive. The container appears to be, but does not scroll horizontally. Does anyone know a work around for this?

[image]

My Code:

```
 <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 table-responsive">
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<HolsteinWebsite_Herdbook.Models.MainAwardsModel>()
                            .Name("TopClassifyingCows_ReportGrid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(c => c.tccGrid.animalName);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.tccGrid.classValue).Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.tccGrid.score).Width(80);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.tccGrid.sireName);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.tccGrid.owners);
                            })
                            .Scrollable()
                            .Sortable()
                            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                .Refresh(true)
                                .PageSizes(true)
                                .ButtonCount(5))
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
                            )
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table" })
                )
  </div>
```

Generated Code:

```
 ...
 <table class="table" role="grid">
            <colgroup>
               <col>
               <col style="width:80px">
               <col style="width:80px">
               <col>
               <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
               <tr class="k-no-data">
                  <td colspan="5"></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
          ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/walkthrough#scrolling

> To achieve horizontal scrolling, all columns must have set widths and their sum must exceed the Grid width. Otherwise widthless columns will shrink to fit in the space determined by the Grid's width.

Also, these links might be useful for your reference when using Kendo UI together with bootstrap:

- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap
- http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/using-kendo-in-responsive-web-pages#widgets-that-do-not-support-auto-resizing-when-container-is-resized